# At build Angular App stops on library function closures Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic/Angular app built using Visual Studio 2013 with Cordova. Every time I build my project it stops on the function closures of many of my js files/libraries. I have to hit resume 5 or 6 times to get my project to finish building. There are obviously no breakpoints in these locations. Is there something I can do to fix this or at least tell visual studio to ignore these locations?

Here is an example:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    //Content
}());  //<<<<-------APP stops here at build
```

This happens very frequently on common angular libraries I have injected into my module as well as well as some of my own js files that are not injected into the module. Here is my module:

```
var mgmtAppModule = angular.module('mgmtAppModule', ['ionic', 'ngResource',  'ngMaterial', 'ngCookies'])
```

Comment: Does it give you some sort of error when it breaks during the build?

Comment: @BenBlack No not at all. Just stops like there is a breakpoint there even if there isn't.

Comment: Hmmmm, strange. The only thing I notice that's "strange" ( I say strange because it's not how I write my code) is that you have `(function(){}()}` rather than `(function(){})();` When you do that, correct me if I'm wrong, it's executing that function right away. Is that what you're intending to do?

Comment: @BenBlack Honestly I copied that from a best practice a while back so not sure if its correct. The exact same thing happens when its done the way you do it as well though... For example the angular-cookies.js, angular-aria.js, angular-resource.js and cordova.js all hit as well. This is the cordova.js one:  (function() { })();

Comment: @BenBlack I tried your way and it didnt help but removing the function wrap fixes the issue for my code. I am obviously having the problem still with the angular libraries as I am a little apprehensive to touch those.

Comment: I'll have to do some more research to see what exactly might cause that, I've never run into an issue like that, but then again I haven't had reason to use Cordova yet either.

Comment: Yeah I work with non cordova angular projects. Never happens then. Surprised there arent others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved with a newer version of cordova for visual studio.